# Xubuntu 15.10 mounting data cd as audio cd

Tags: sound, mount, xubuntu, cd

I am trying to run a game on my Xubuntu machine. When I put the CD in for the game it recognizes it as an audio CD with a "Track 2.wav" that is the same size as the collective files on the disk. When I try to mount the cd, it gives me the error

```
ray@gilberts:~$ sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt
[sudo] password for ray: 
mount: /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

I decide to do what it says and I get this:

```
ray@gilberts:~$ dmesg | tail
[  368.511331] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[  368.511333] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 04 91 ba 00 00 01 00 00 00
[  368.511335] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1197800
[  368.511337] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 299450, async page read
[  368.512164] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  368.512165] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  368.512168] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[  368.512169] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 04 91 bb 00 00 01 00 00 00
[  368.512171] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1197804
[  368.512172] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 299451, async page read
```

The CD works in my windows machine and other CDs work in my Xubuntu machine. In fact, I only have two CDs that are doing this, but they work in my windows machine.

Comment: You probably aren't going to be able to play a Windows game CD in Ubuntu, just so you know.

Comment: It works just fine under Wine, the base game anyway. The expansions are the CDs that won't mount.

Comment: Wine confines apps to sandboxes. I'm almost certain I've seen reports that CD expansions can't be made to work

Comment: Even mounting the CD? I didn't figure that really had anything to do with Wine.

Comment: It doesn't. I'm just trying to dissuade you from trying something pointless. It's probable that the CD is copy protected and that Ubuntu can't read it

Answer (score 1):

I was just facing the same problem after trying out CDs of old Windows 95 games on Ubuntu 16.04.

Some background: Back in the days, CDs of Windows games contained both a data track and audio tracks. The game data is on the data track, and the audio tracks were for the in-game audio. You can actually insert these CDs in a regular CD player and it will play the music from track 2 and up.

Ubuntu recognizes these types of CDs as audio CDs, which is thus not entirely incorrect. But you can easily mount the data track with the following command:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/cdrom/
sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /mnt/cdrom/
```

Then can you can open the directory /mnt/cdrom/ with your file browser to view the data content of the CD. Then you can proceed to install the game with Wine. But you might also need DosBox for the older games.